# C# and VB.NET operator precedence

Tags: c#, vb.net

Looking at the C# and VB.NET language specs I think it says that the logical Xor/Or/And operations have different precendence in the two languages. Am I reading that right? I was expecting them to have the same precendence.

For example in C#

```
100 | 200 ^ 300 & 400
```

is the same as...

```
100 | (200 ^ (300 & 400))
```

But the equivalent VB.NET

```
100 Or 200 Xor 300 And 400
```

as far as I can tell is the same as...

```
(100 Or 200) Xor (300 And 400)
```

Am I reading that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I reading that right?

Yes. Simple as that.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I'm not a fan of remembering precedence rules. If there is *any* ambiguity, I just add brackets. Even if I get it right, somebody else might have to read it, and I don't know which background they'll have...

But I think you are reading it correctly.